# Как правильно писать: всяко-разно или всяко разно?

Tags: орфография

-

Answer (score 1):

Для точного ответа не хватает контекста, но если рассматривать эту конструкцию как наречие (а как еще? не будем же мы предполагать, что здесь какие народно-разговорные или просторечные слова - краткие прилагательные ), то вспоминается известное правило:"Наречия, образованные повторением слов или повторением синонимичных слов, пишутся через дефис"